# How to show custom loading icon/spinner in Keno UI mobile?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

How would I use a custom spinner in Kendo UI Mobile to change the default loading image?

Perhaps one of the spinners from this page:

http://www.queness.com/post/9150/9-javascript-and-animated-gif-loading-animation-solutions

I have searched, but can't find specific information.

Comment: which spinner exactly are you talking about? can you create a demo?

Answer (score 0):

The new loader is fully CSS so im not certain you can use an animated gif although you may try subsituting the background css statement with a background-image tag and see what happens

you can style the .km-loader element to achieve a look similar to the old one, like this:

```
.km-ios .km-loader {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

See this jsbin for a more detailed reach into the different states of the loader http://jsbin.com/uwupay/6/edit?html,output